# VBA - copy method requires activating sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code deletes a few columns from a specific sheet and copies what's left to a separate sheet:

```
Sub Test()

    Daily.Range("C:D,G:G,J:M,O:P").EntireColumn.Delete
    Daily.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Work.Range("C2")


End Sub
```

If I run this an I am not on the Daily sheet I get a run-time error: 
method range of object _worksheet failed

If I add a line

```
Daily.Activate
```

It works fine.

Can someone explain how does it work? Do I really have to activate a sheet before copying from it?

Comment: Try declaring the workbook aswell and it shouldn't give you any problem:

`Set wb = ThisWorkbook`
`Set Daily = wb.Sheets("Daily")` or whatever is called the sheet

Comment: @Damian `Daily` is the code name of the worksheet, so it will *always* be scoped to the workbook it resides in. Retrieving it from the `Sheets` collection by name is much more fragile code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're referencing a Range without specifying which worksheet to use, so that it defaults to the active worksheet:

```
Daily.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy …
```

Try

```
Daily.Range("A2", Daily.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy …
```